Promotion approved this month but not awarded until August. Can I add this to job apps
My promotion and tenure have been approved but don't officially take effect until next semester. Unfortunately, my University will be closing in the summer of 2025 so I will be applying for jobs this fall. Is there a way to put on my CV that my promotion to associate professor and tenure have been approved for any job apps that are due before next semester?

Sure, say you’ve been promoted. Is there something about that that seems unnatural?

Don't say or imply that you are now an associate professor (or whatever). But it is easy enough to say that you have been promoted to associate professor effective "some future date". That is accurate and honest. It won't be misunderstood.
It is probably overkill but you could also give the date the decision was finalized. But don't omit the effective date.
And, for many such applications, you might be awarded the associate professor title but still need to go through a short (maybe 2 year) probationary period before you get actual tenure. That can happen even when a full professor moves institutions.
